# How to call DLL from another application in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, dll

I am new in Qt development and developing Qt DLL which start TCP Server.When i am calling dll from my another app it will not receive any new connection socket.
So please guide me if i am doing any wrong step.

Server.h

```
extern "C" SERVERSHARED_EXPORT void CallServer();
class SERVERSHARED_EXPORT Server :  public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Server();
    void CallServer();
    void CallServer1();

    QTcpServer *server;
    QTcpSocket *socket ;
signals:
public slots:
    void myConnection();
    void closingClient();
};
```

Server.cpp

```
  Server::Server()
{

}

void CallServer()
{
    Server server_Obj;
    server_Obj.CallServer1();
    while (true)
        ::sleep(1000);
}

void Server::CallServer1()
{
    server = new QTcpServer(this);
    connect(server, SIGNAL(newConnection()),this, SLOT(myConnection()));

    QHostAddress hostadd(ServerIP);

    qDebug() << ServerIP;
    qDebug() << Port;

    if(!server->listen(hostadd,Port.toInt()))        qDebug() << "\nWeb server     could not start";
    else                                             qDebug() <<"\nWeb server is waiting for a connection";

}

void Server::myConnection()
{
    qDebug() << "Detected Connection";
    QByteArray Rdata;
    socket = server->nextPendingConnection();

    qDebug() << "Wait for connect = " << socket->waitForConnected();

    while (socket->waitForReadyRead(10))
    {
        while(socket->bytesAvailable() > 0)
        {
            Rdata.append(socket->readAll());
        }
    }

    qDebug() << "Final Testing is size = " << Rdata.size();
    qDebug() << "Final Testing is" << Rdata;
}
```

.pro file

```
QT       += core
QT       += network
QT      += widgets
QT       -= gui

TARGET = Server
TEMPLATE = lib

DEFINES += SERVER_LIBRARY

SOURCES += server.cpp 
HEADERS += server.h\
        server_global.h
```

Another App:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);


    QLibrary library("Server.dll");
     if (!library.load())
        qDebug() << library.errorString();
     if (library.load())
         qDebug() << "library loaded";

     typedef int(*pf)(void);
     pf cwf = (pf)library.resolve("CallServer");
     if (cwf) {
      int x = cwf();
     } else {
      qDebug() << "Could not show widget from the loaded library";
     }

     qDebug() << "After call";

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: So you are calling it *"qt"* and *"QT"*, and somehow decidedly left out the correct spelling: *"Qt"*. Good luck, if that is the amount of diligence you are willing to invest.

Comment: There's an infinite `sleep` call loop in your code.

Comment: sleep is added because i want  to check server is running or not otherwise It returns back.

Comment: I don't think `sleep` does what you think it does. There's no exit point to your loop; it just sleeps indefinitely.

Comment: But if i remove sleep then call returns and server is no more in listening mode .I want suggestion how can i call server from another app using load dll. sorry for not so good English.

Comment: Same server code working as executable but not as dll.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's not working because you are using QTcpSocket (your Server class) in asynchronous (signals/slots) way WITHOUT event loop - so it'll not work. You should add an event loop or use sockets in a blocking manner. For more details look at - http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-blockingfortuneclient-example.html